# 'System.Collections.Generic.List<float>' does not contain a definition for 'Sum'

Tags: c#, list, sum

I am trying to Sum a list of floats with built in `Sum()` function but I keep getting this error :

> Error CS1061: 'System.Collections.Generic.List' does not
>   contain a definition for 'Sum' and no extension method 'Sum' accepting
>   a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?) (CS1061)

and I have

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

in the beginning of the file:

code :

```
List<float> x = new List<float>();
x.add(5.0f);
//..
float f = x.Sum();
```

Comment: Why am I getting - for this question ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to add to your `using` directives:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Besides, your code is syntactically wrong. Here's the working version:

```
var x = new List<float>();
x.Add(5.0f);
var f = x.Sum();
```

Comment: I beg to differ on your stating his code is "syntctically wrong". The only reason you need to use "var" is when you don't really care to know, or using non-generic types, when creating a declaration statement.